# PHP Fatal error out of memory while building tree

Tags: php, arrays, tree, out-of-memory

I got trouble with bulding tree of categories in php.
It's builds tree for very long time and after that i got error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 637796352) (tried to allocate
>   208666926 bytes) in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\site.local\Core\Widgets.php on line 488

Here is my functions to build tree.

First i made an array of categories:

```
public function makeCategoriesArray()
        {
//            $row = DB::select()
//                ->from('catalog_tree')
//                ->where('parent_id', '=', $this->post['parent_id'])
//                ->union(DB::select()
//                    ->from('catalog_tree')
//                    ->where('id', 'in', DB::expr("(SELECT catalog_tree_id FROM catalog_tree_parents WHERE parent_id = '".$this->post['parent_id']."')")))
//                ->find_all();
            $row = DB::select()
                ->from('catalog_tree')
                ->where('status', '=', '1')
                ->find_all();
            $categories_arr = array();
            foreach ($row as $cat) {
                $categories_arr[$cat->parent_id][] = $cat;
            }
            unset($cat);
            unset($row);

            foreach($categories_arr as $key=>$value) {
                $row = DB::select()
                    ->from('catalog_tree')
                    ->where('id', 'in', DB::expr("(SELECT catalog_tree_id FROM catalog_tree_parents WHERE parent_id = '".$key."')"))
                    ->find_all();

                foreach($row as $cat) {
                    $categories_arr[$key][] = $cat;
                }
                unset($cat);
                unset($row);
            }

            return $categories_arr;
        }
```

Then i begin to build tree with this array:

```
public function BuildMainTree($array, $pid) {

            global $MainMenu;

            if (isset($array[$pid])) { // If category with $pid exist

                $MainMenu.= "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">";

                foreach ($array[$pid] as $value)
                {
                   if ($pid!='0' && !isset($array[$value->id])) {

                       $MainMenu.= '<li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="/catalog/' . $value->alias . '">
                                            '. $value->name .' 
                                        </a>
                                    </li>';
                   }
                   else {

                       $MainMenu.= '<li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="/catalog/' . $value->alias . '">
                                            '. $value->name .' 
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>';
                       $this->BuildMainTree($array, $value->id);
                   }
                }
                if ($pid=='0') {
                    $MainMenu .= "</ul>";
                }
                else {
                    $MainMenu .= "</ul></li>";
                }
            }
        }
```

Initialization of this process are in this function:

```
 public function Header() {
            $contentMenu = Common::factory('sitemenu')->getRows(1, 'sort');
            $array['contentMenu'] = $contentMenu;
            $array['user'] = User::info();
            $array['countItemsInTheCart'] = Cart::factory()->_count_goods;

            $categories_arr = $this->makeCategoriesArray();
            $this->BuildMainTree($categories_arr, 0);
            $array['mainMenu'] = $MainMenu;

            return $array;
        }
```

Also if i just make array with **makeCategoriesArray()** it's works fine, but **BuildMainTree($array, $pid)** function causes an error...

Most funny part, is that this code works perfect on other site.

Maybe I just missed some details here... Spent two days of tried to run this code, but got nothing.

Here is array var_dump:

```
array(156) {
  [0]=>
  array(21) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#17 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2075"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1473775697"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Садовая мебель"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(14) "sadovaja-mebel"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "outdoor"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "dc30302d5e76ddf7d3be9cb0f8b4d711.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "129"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#19 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2076"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1473950659"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(39) "Оформление интерьера"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(19) "oformlenie-interera"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(10) "decoration"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "91b3786d06e22081abbb945b9e4e02d8.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "287"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#20 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2077"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472474523"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Офисная мебель"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(14) "ofisnaja-mebel"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(10) "workspaces"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "6884cb6cf5defdf8ec7fe467bad542ca.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "247"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#21 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2078"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472409476"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(34) "Посуда для готовки"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(19) "posuda-dlja-gotovki"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "cooking"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "ca3e4a8eb9d0d7ea22f9a7fc3c300ef9.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "514"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(stdClass)#22 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2079"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472547042"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Столовая"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(9) "stolovaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(6) "dining"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "d5704ec3e70a3415b181c7c4f9005c1a.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "147"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#23 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2080"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472547236"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(31) "Сервировка стола"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(16) "servirovka-stola"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(6) "eating"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "2d2142a8edd5fc3ce1ffa01fbe6655c9.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "338"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [6]=>
    object(stdClass)#24 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2081"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472540142"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(21) "Кухни МЕТОД"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(11) "kuhni-metod"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "kitchen"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "decf1d321c63aed673d949b34c452a37.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "304"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#25 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2082"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472466401"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "Освещение"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(11) "osveschenie"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(8) "lighting"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "3ac3d00a4734040cf346f2a63a09a7f9.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "243"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [8]=>
    object(stdClass)#26 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2083"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472547518"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Детская"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(8) "detskaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(14) "childrens_ikea"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "8d78781b99b8ee7a1abc0f9cbfdc7e01.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "321"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [9]=>
    object(stdClass)#27 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2084"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472411322"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Гостиная"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(9) "gostinaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(11) "living_room"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "c9c933ae12652bca96eb2ef66c832a82.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "181"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [10]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2085"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472388754"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(35) "Домашняя прачечная"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(24) "domashnjaja-prachechnaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "laundry"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "08c9713d828235679b861c095784af0e.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "106"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [11]=>
    object(stdClass)#29 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2086"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472481068"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(45) "Дополнительное хранение"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(22) "dopolnitelnoe-hranenie"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(17) "secondary_storage"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "bb180b85cc1e34ab9b6185f4cf71fbf0.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "158"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [12]=>
    object(stdClass)#31 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2088"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472136224"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Прихожая"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(10) "prihozhaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "hallway"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "985600d075b4080f57488b87e0e898ff.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(2) "64"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [13]=>
    object(stdClass)#32 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2089"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472556911"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Спальня"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(7) "spalnja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(7) "bedroom"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "439a1f90391568bffabcfbc5a8b22559.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "172"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [14]=>
    object(stdClass)#33 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2090"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472481070"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "Еда в ИКЕА"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(10) "eda-v-ikea"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(4) "food"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "1886868c925ed2f22a10fe7e51a6050c.JPG"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(2) "24"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [15]=>
    object(stdClass)#34 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2091"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472554267"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Текстиль"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(7) "tekstil"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(8) "Textiles"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "1ed5b13bc1abab2d5966b6ab074b7174.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "194"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [16]=>
    object(stdClass)#35 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2092"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1473774214"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(33) "Домашние растения"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(19) "domashnie-rastenija"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(16) "indoor_gardening"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "a42bf2728494d635bc16b0f12db5855d.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["views"]=>
      string(2) "55"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [17]=>
    object(stdClass)#36 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2093"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472481066"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(39) "Беспроводная зарядка"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(22) "besprovodnaja-zarjadka"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(17) "wireless_charging"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "6ee6de2d3769d7f617b7e05fd81fbaa4.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(2) "95"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [18]=>
    object(stdClass)#37 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2094"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472517463"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Ванная"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(7) "vannaja"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(8) "bathroom"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "f69159cedca764bc7d44ff7d6a13b52a.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "157"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [19]=>
    object(stdClass)#38 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2095"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472379447"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(24) "Товары IKEA FAMILY"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(18) "tovary-ikea-family"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(20) "ikea_family_products"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "9e0c8d67fd4189ebed7b821e1c6b9df8.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(2) "78"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [20]=>
    object(stdClass)#39 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "2096"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(10) "1470080793"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(10) "1472482584"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["name"]=>
      string(34) "Для вашего бизнеса"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(20) "dlja-vashego-biznesa"
      ["ikea_alias"]=>
      string(8) "business"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["image"]=>
      string(36) "3b9d8f1d77703f38d3d043fb95dd2b5e.jpg"
      ["h1"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["keywords"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["text"]=>
      NULL
      ["views"]=>
      string(3) "118"
      ["course"]=>
      string(4) "9.50"
      ["discount_percent"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
```

Comment: please add var_dump of a minimal example Array, it Looks like this line is the Problem: $this->BuildMainTree($array, $value->id); if $value->id stays 0 then you get endless recursion

Comment: Doesn't this throw an error `$categories_arr[$cat->parent_id][] = $cat`? You are adding a new array item to `$categories_arr[$cat->parent_id]` without making it into an array first.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, added var_dump of $array

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, the is no errors in that part of code. Only while building tree...

Comment: @ViacheslavZhabonos try to add $array = $array[0]; as first line of the function

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, got this: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\OpenServer\domains\site.local\Core\Widgets.php on line 473

Comment: @ViacheslavZhabonos thanks, i would really suggest to look into this condition: ($pid!='0' && !isset($array[$value->id])) Maybe make a Breakpoint in there or echo something to see if this ever occurs. In your dump it Looks like $value->id is always set, so your recursion will go one forever. I bet it should be parent_id and not id ^^

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, thanks, I will try this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this function:

```
public static function BuildTree($pid) {

            global $MainMenu;

            $row = DB::select()
                ->from('catalog_tree')
                ->where('parent_id', '=', $pid)
                ->and_where('status', '=', '1')
                ->union(DB::select()
                    ->from('catalog_tree')
                    ->where('id', 'in', DB::expr("(SELECT catalog_tree_id FROM catalog_tree_parents WHERE parent_id = '".$pid."')"))
                    ->and_where('status', '=', '1'))
                ->find_all();

            if ($row->count() > 0) {

                $MainMenu .= "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">";

                foreach ($row as $value)
                {

                        $MainMenu .= '                                       
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="/catalog/' . $value->alias . '">
                                            '. $value->name .' 
                                        </a> ';

                    Widgets::BuildTree($value->id);
                }
                if ($pid=='0') {
                    $MainMenu .= " <li class=\"divider\"></li></ul>";
                    return $MainMenu;
                }
                else {
                    $MainMenu .= " <li class=\"divider\"></li></ul></li>";
                }
            }
        }
```

This function works perfectly :)
I think @DoktorOSwaldo was right, previous recursion was endless.

Answer (score 1):

that is not a code issue. set memory_limit in php.ini file to more than 128m,
you should also increase post meta data to something like 10000